# Debugging Cordova / Phonegap on device not showing changes

Tags: android, cordova, adt, cordova-3

I'm just getting started with developing android apps with cordova/phonegab.

Everything is installed, blank sample app is running. However it seems changes are not shown. So basically it seems I'm stuck with the first build. I think cordova isn't making a build before running the debugger?!

How do I debug a cordova phonegap app with eclipse adt? Are there any best practices?

Another side question. ADT is either opening the browser or a simple text editor. Isn't were any code highlighting / code editor integrated into eclipse adt?

Thx. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: please setup android emulator and then import your cordova/phonegap project in eclipse and then run the project in emulator. you will able to debug by using eclipse LogCat.

Comment: already done. However I'm allways getting the first version and no new builds are made

Comment: is your build app name is Hello world?

Comment: no it's not hello world and this doesn't matter! I'm changing html. I can build and run it on device with shell command cordova run. However if I run or debug it with eclipse it always shows the latest build i did from shell and not rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are following the process correctly but confused due to appname as everytime you create project with below command you app name will be Helloworld

```
phonegap create project_name
```

try creating a new project like this

```
phonegap create hello com.example.hello hello
```

then load it in eclipse and run.